# How can I prevent Division tags in HTML to disort

Tags: html, css

this is my first question and I hope I would get some help here.

I have made this HTML page that has 5 DIV's mainly:

- Header
- Content
- Footer

  **Content contains**
- Left
- Right

The Left and Right Div's float on Left and right respectively.When I put something **content div** with an H1 tag the div's get somewhat disorted and **I get a approx. 10px space between the header and content section, somewhat like this:**

[Disorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m41z.png)

However the original one should be:

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZY7yl.png)

```
        <body>
<a target="_blank"><div id="main" >
<div id="header" >

<a style="color:#000000" href="home.html">Home</a>
<a style="color:#000000" href="about.html">about</a>
<a style="color:#000000" href="Our customers.html">Our Customers</a>
<a style="color:#000000" href="Career.html">Careers</a>
<a style="color:#000000" href="Contact us.html">Contact us</a>
</div>
<div id="content">
<div id="left" ></div>
<div id="right" ></div>
Home
</div>
<div id="footer">
<a style="color:#FFFFFF" href="home.html">Privacy Policy</a>|
<a style="color:#FFFFFF" href="Feedback.html">Feedback</a>|
<a style="color:#FFFFFF" href="disclaimer.html">Disclaimer</a>|
<a style="color:#FFFFFF" href="Manadatory.html">Manadatory Disclosure</a>|
<a style="color:#FFFFFF" href="sitemap.html">Site Map</a>|
</div>
</div></body>
```

Here is my CSS Code:

```
#main
{
height:900px;
background-color:#000000;
}
#header
{
    height:100px;
background-color:#00FF00;
padding:70px;
    padding-right:70px;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align:center;
    background-image:url(Images/text3.jpg);
    padding: 50px;
}
#content

{
height:700px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
#left
{
float:left;
 height:700px;
 background-color:#FF0000;
 width:150px;
 background-image:url(Images/navbar2.jpg);
}
   #right
{
float:right;
 height:700px;
 background-color:#FF0000;
 width:150px;
  background-image:url(Images/navbar2.jpg);
}


#footer
{
padding:50px;
padding-right:70px;
font-size:20px;
text-align:center;
height:100px;
background-image:url(Images/footer.jpg);
}
```

Fixing position of the div's using position hasn't helped. Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: Thats collapsing margins from the sound of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click and inspect element on your browser and check the divs. You should see what's happening to it. Most likely it will be some default styling that's giving some margins. That's why most people use some kind of reset.css as a clean base. I imagine the default css is applying margins to the `<p>` and `<h1>` tags.

Maybe try adding something like:

```
h1 {
    margin:0;
}
```

Obviously you could specify only certain margins rather than all or .content h1{} to just apply styling to the headers within the content block.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will let you know if the above workaround fixes.